# Globally replace a particular pattern with another string

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace

In VI I need to replace a pattern that looks like this:

seq- followed by exactly 24 chars (can be 0-9, a-z, A-Z only) followed by / followed by some number of (0-9, a-z, A-Z). So an example string would be:

```
seq-BzFk78qrJBkbnv1KkxppsfG4/92191_A_B
```

I want to replace the above string with a fixed string:

```
seq-ID/NUM_ID
```

How do I do this in Vi or Vim? I tried a few things like

```
:%s/seq-[a-zA-Z0-9]{24}\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{+}/seq-ID\/NUM_ID
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't cross post http://stackoverflow.com/q/39714301/1890567

Answer (score 6):

There are many problems with your regex.

1. `{24}` will not match 24 of the previous atom, it will match the text `{24}`. I doubt this is what you want. You need a backslash e.g. `\{24}`. Additionally you could enable "Very magic", e.g. `\v{24}`
2. In your example, the text after the slash has underscores in it, e.g. `92191_A_B`. Change `[a-zA-Z-0-9]` to `[a-zA-Z-0-9_]`
3. "One or more" is `\+`, *not* `{+}`.

There are also some style problems.

1. If you are going to search for something containing slashes, you should use a different separator, e.g.

   ```
   :%s;seq-[a-zA-Z0-9]{24}/[a-zA-Z0-9]{+};seq-ID/NUM_ID
   ```

   For more readability.
2. Don't use `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` when you could just use `\w`. I would also use this in place of `[a-zA-Z0-9]` unless it's possible that underscores will be in there, and you want to avoid matching this. In this case, `\c[a-z0-9]` is also shorter

Putting this all together, I would recommend going with:

```
:%s;\vseq-\w{24}/\w+;seq-ID/NUM_ID
```

I would also highly recommend reading through [vim regex](http://vimregex.com/). One of the best quick intros to vim's regex engine I have ever seen. I have it bookmarked in my browser at all times for quick reference.